# Max values per tag limit exceeded InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I am using java and writing into InfluxDb using batch points. My code is mention below,

```
 BatchPoints batchPoints = BatchPoints
.database(dbName).retentionPolicy("autogen") .consistency(InfluxDB.ConsistencyLevel.ALL).build();


    point = Point.measurement("cpu")...

    batchPoints.point(point);
```

I am writing 20 to 30 Million points, and after a while getting exception:

```
.java.lang.RuntimeException: {"error":"partial write: max-values-per-tag limit exceeded (100708/100000): measurement=\"cpu\" tag=\"jkey\" value=\ .....
```

Wondering how to increase the limit? Or do i need to change my schema design?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the solution so pasting here, open influxdb.conf file usually located at /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf and search for:

```
# max-values-per-tag = 100000
```

uncomment and replace the value to zero as shown below,

```
max-values-per-tag = 0
```

And bounce the influxDb instance for changes to take effect.

Comment: I have found that too. My concern is: isn't 1M rows not that much for a time-series DB? I believe that 1M row shouldn't be a problem and, nevertheless, this limit makes me think the opposite ...

Comment: Yes, by default values allowed per-tag is pretty low. It should be at least 10 times of it.

Comment: Adding link to more info: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/administration/config/#max-values-per-tag-100000

Comment: @Ammad actually 10000 is already a quite big value for this parameter. It's about unique values for a given tag key. Each such unique value produces new series (one can treat them as files on the disk). Having 10000 separate files is already a bit strange. But to have a 1e6 files is unreasonable.

Comment: This may be a "solution" but unless you really know what you are doing, chances are your InfluxDB schema is using tags in a non-optimal way. In general, tags should have few unique values. Further reference: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/

Comment: @GustavoBezerra :  Why not, I have vehicle id as tag key which can go in millions. I use id as tag because I generally have to filter via vehicle

Comment: @Nipun: Sure, that sounds like a legit use case. But I have seen people using tags for things that really weren't tags at all, therefore my warning. With indexes not in memory anymore (using TSI) unique tag values in the millions should be ok.

Comment: It's the cardinality level and the main attribution to it is that the level of cardinality is upper bound, so there's some limit to it. For the rest, the cardinality level affects the size and efficiency of the index and storage compactness. But again, InfluxDB boldly claims to be able to ingest millions of data points per second. I can hardly imagine that it might come from 100000 devices if you use device id as a tag.

Comment: updated url https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/administration/config/#max-values-per-tag--100000

Comment: influxdb增加了对tag的值的大小的校验，最大值是10000.若写入的数据的tag的值超限，则调用方会收到报错。用来防止写入到measurement的数据的series-cardinality( series-cardinality)过大。如果我们写入了大量的series-cardinality很高的数据，那么当我们删除数据的时候，InfluxDB会OOM。

原因是InfluxDB在内存中维护了系统中每个series数据的索引。随着具有唯一性的series数据数量的增长，RAM的使用也会增长。过高的series cardinality会导致操作系统kill掉InfluxDB进程，抛出OOM异常。

作者：大地缸
链接：https://www.jianshu.com/p/d8bd844f2304
来源：简书
著作权归作者所有。商业转载请联系作者获得授权，非商业转载请注明出处。

Comment: set to max-values-per-tag = 0 is not a good idea.